# C++: How to use extern variables in a struct

Tags: c++, c++11, struct

I try to implement a piece of software, following a ETSI specification.
Now i have to write a struct, in which a variable is declared as extern.

```
file2.cpp
struct struct_one {
    extern Algo algo;
    int x;
}
```

---

```
file1.cpp
struct struct_two {
    Algo algo;
    char c;
}
```

So, how do i "tell" the compiler, that the two "algo" variables contain the same things?
Is it enough to include file1 in file2?

Or what do i have to do?

Greetings

Comment: §9.2/6 "A member shall not be declared with the `extern` or `register` *storage-class-specifier*. ..." This doesn't answer your question, though. I suspect what you really want is to forward declare a struct/class. Take a look at the [pimpl idiom](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/028.htm).

Comment: If both of them are the same... Can you use a pointer or reference?

Comment: I am pretty sure theres something wrong. If I create 2 instancecs of struct_two and only one instance of struct_one, what will the instance of struct_one contain? Extern keyword is used to declare a variable that is defined in another source file which would get resolved while linking...

Comment: Do you mean `static`?

Comment: Do you mean the type is the same or the contents is the same or they should be at the same place in memory?

Comment: No, i do not realy mean static. I'm following the specification, wich tells: "The necessary algorithm shall be given as an external link to the parameter algo specified in the structur struct_two"

Comment: What, exactly, are the intended semantics for `struct_one`'s `algo`?

Comment: Algo is only a enum, its to identify the further use of sturct_one. So, i have to know which enum is in struct_two to figure out how to use the integer.

Comment: @ChristinaObermaier Is said spec available online?

Comment: @ChristinaObermaier: "I have to know which enum is in struct_two" - but different instances of `struct_two` can have different values. If it's meant to be a single value, independent of any instance of `struct_two`, then it needs to either a static member, or a non-member. If `struct_one` is supposed to get the value from a particular instance of `struct_two`, then you'll need to initialise the value (or possibly a reference or pointer) in each `struct_one` instance from its corresponding `struct_two` instance. From the vague description here, it's hard to say what the answer might be.

Comment: Its this specification [link](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/103000_103099/103097/01.01.01_60/ts_103097v010101p.pdf). My question is about topic 4.2.5 EccPoint, where the PublicKeyAlgorithm is declared as extern..

Comment: @ChristinaObermaier: From table 1 (which specifies the presentation language for describing the data structures, which is not C++), `extern` means "this is external data which has impact on a struct". It's not (necessarily) meant to be a member, but does have an effect - in this case, on the value of `field_size`.

Comment: Yes, i think i understand it. But i thougt it would be the easiest way to save the needed data. But now i decided to implement it in an other way. I pass the "extern" data directly to the function, wich uses struct_one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that, but you can do it this way:

```
file1.cpp
struct struct_two {
    Algo algo;
    char c;
}

file2.cpp
struct struct_one {
    explicit struct_one(struct_two& t) : algo(t.algo) {}

    Algo& algo;
    int x;
}
```

or use combination pattern('has a' relationship):

```
file1.cpp
struct struct_two {
    Algo algo;
    char c;
}

file2.cpp
struct struct_one {
    struct_two t;
    int x;
}
```